# Python How to clear window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to clear window before I load a new map. But menu buttons have to stay. I was trying self.frame.destroy(), but it kill my menu buttons too. Basically I need to clear class Sokoban, but this class is not in class Window. Problem is in **def map1(self):** and **def map2(self):**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Sokoban')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Mapa1', command = self.map1)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Mapy', menu=file)

        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label='Mapa2', command = self.map2)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit)

    def map1(self):
        self.frame.forget()
        Sokoban('map1.txt')

    def map2(self):
        self.frame.forget()
        Sokoban('map2.txt')


class Sokoban:

    def __init__(self, subor):
        t = open(subor, 'r')
        self.pole = [None] * 8
        self.box = []
        for a in range(8):
            self.pole[a] = list(t.readline().strip())
            for b in range(len(self.pole[a])):
                if self.pole[a][b] == '$':
                    self.player = Player(a,b)
                    self.pole[a][b] = '.'
                if self.pole[a][b] == '@':
                    self.box.append(Box(a,b))
                    self.pole[a][b] = '.'
        t.close()
        self.game = self.g = tkinter.Canvas(bg = 'white', width = 650, height = 240,
                                cursor = 'cross')
        self.g.pack()
        self.farba = [['gray'],['khaki'],['#FF4500'],['yellow'],['brown']]
        stena = '*'
        policko = '.'
        player = '$'
        box = '@'
        ciel = '+'
##        self.newButt = self.g.create_rectangle(511, 0, 650, 45, fill = 'red')
##        self.newButtText = self.g.create_text(580.5, 22.5, text = 'New Game',
##                                               font = 'arial 19 italic bold',
##                                              fill = 'yellow')
##        self.map1Butt = self.g.create_rectangle(511, 46, 650, 86, fill = 'red')
##        self.map1ButtText = self.g.create_text(580.5, 66, text = 'Map - 1',
##                                               font = 'arial 19 italic bold',
##                                               fill = 'yellow')
##        self.map2Butt = self.g.create_rectangle(511, 87, 650, 127, fill = 'red')
##        self.map2ButtText = self.g.create_text(580.5, 109, text = 'Map - 2',
##                                               font = 'arial 19 italic bold',
##                                               fill = 'yellow')
##        self.map3Butt = self.g.create_rectangle(511, 128, 650, 168, fill = 'red')
##        self.map3ButtText = self.g.create_text(580.5, 148, text = 'Map - 3',
##                                               font = 'arial 19 italic bold',
##                                               fill = 'yellow')
        self.kresli()
        self.g.bind_all('<Up>', self.up)
        self.g.bind_all('<Down>', self.down)
        self.g.bind_all('<Left>', self.left)
        self.g.bind_all('<Right>', self.right)
##        self.g.bind('<1>', self.Buttons)


    def up(self, e):
        self.move(-1, 0)

    def down(self, e):
        self.move(1, 0)

    def left(self, e):
        self.move(0, -1)

    def right(self, e):
        self.move(0, 1)

##    def newGame(self):
##        self.game.pack_forget()
##        Sokoban()

##    def map1(self):
##        self.game.pack_forget()
##        Sokoban('map1.txt')
##
##    def map2(self):
##        self.game.pack_forget()
##        Sokoban('map2.txt')

##    def Buttons(self, e):
##        if '<1>' and self.newButt:
##            self.newGame()

##        if '<1>' and self.map1Butt:
##            self.map1()
##
##        if '<1>' and self.map2Butt:
##            self.map2()

    def kresli(self):
        for a in range(8):
            for b in range(17):
                x,y = b*30, a*30
                f = self.farba['*.+'.index(self.pole[a][b])]
                self.g.create_rectangle(x,y,x+30,y+30,fill=f)
        self.player.kresli(self.g, self.farba[3])
        for box in self.box:
            box.kresli(self.g, self.farba[4])

    def setBox(self, r, s):
        for a in range(len(self.box)):
            if self.box[a].r==r and self.box[a].s==s:
                return a
        return -1

    def move(self, dr, ds):
        r = self.player.r + dr
        s = self.player.s + ds
        if r<0 or r>=8 or s<0 or s>=510 or self.pole[r][s] == '*':
            return
        c = self.setBox(r, s)
        if c >= 0:
            rr = r + dr
            ss = s + ds
            if rr < 0 or rr>=8 or ss<0 or ss>=510 or self.pole[rr][ss] == '*':
                return
            if self.setBox(rr, ss) >= 0:
                return
            self.box[c].move(dr, ds)
        self.player.move(dr, ds)

        for c in self.box:
            if self.pole[c.r][c.s] != '+':
                return

class Player:

    def __init__(self, r, s):
        self.r = r
        self.s = s

    def kresli(self, g, farba):
        self.g = g
        x,y = self.s*30, self.r*30
        self.plr = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='player.png')
        self.id1 = g.create_image(x+15, y+15, image = self.plr)

    def move(self, dr, ds):
        self.r = self.r + dr
        self.s = self.s + ds
        self.g.move(self.id1, ds*30, dr*30)

class Box:

    def __init__(self, r, s):
        self.r = r
        self.s = s

    def kresli(self, g, farba):
        self.g = g
        x,y = self.s*30, self.r*30
        self.bx = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='box.png')
        self.id2 = g.create_image(x+15, y+15, image = self.bx)

    def move(self, dr, ds):
        self.r = self.r + dr
        self.s = self.s + ds
        self.g.move(self.id2, ds*30, dr*30)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('510x240')
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
Sokoban()
```

Answer (score 2):

That not-working wall of code is very hard to work with so I will try to answer your *menu buttons have to stay* part with an example code. 
Basically you create two frames, one holds widgets going to be cleared and second one holds other widgets plus first frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2 = tk.Frame(frame1)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()
menubar = tk.Menu(frame1) 
menubar.add_command(label="Bring Back!", command=frame2.pack)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=root.destroy)

tk.Button(frame2, text="Forget only frame2", command=frame2.pack_forget).pack()
tk.Label(frame2, text="Label on frame2").pack()

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```